# Arduino Linker Errors When Using a Spesific Namespace Name

Tags: c++, namespaces, arduino

I am trying to write an Arduino library.

I have put all my code inside a namespace and got some linker errors.

Strangely, when I changed the **name** of the namespace these errors were gone.

My question is what could be the cause of this? Can it be that this namespace is already used by some other library?

#### Minimal example:

at24c256.h

```
#ifndef AT24C256
#define AT24C256

namespace AT24C256 {
  int f();
}

#endif
```

at24c256.cpp

```
#include "at24c256.h"

namespace AT24C256 {
  int f() {return 42;}
}
```

And then in the sketch, I just call `AT24C256::f()`.

```
#include "at24c256.h"

void setup() { 
}

void loop() {
    AT24C256::f();
}
```

All three files are in the same directory.
The error I got in this case is:

> sketch_dec13b.cpp: In function ‘void loop()’:
>   sketch_dec13b.cpp:155:13: error: ‘::f’ has not been declared

If I change AT24C256 to something else, the build completes without errors.

**Update:**

I accidentally posted the wrong error message. What I actually get is this:

> sketch_jan04a.cpp.o: In function `loop': 
> sketch_jan04a.cpp:10: undefined reference to `(anonymous namespace)::f()' 
> collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, I finally found out what the problem was. The include guards defined AT24C256 which is exactly the name of my namespace, so it was preprocessed into nothing.

Answer (score 1):

```
‘::f’ has not been declared
```

This shows us that you call the function `f()` at global scope. When you want to use the function you must be in the same scope or specify the scope explicitly.

**Edit**

Your header file shows the problem now after your edit:

```
#ifndef AT24C256
#define AT24C256

namespace AT24C256 {
```

Your are using an anonymous namespace.

`AT24C256::f()` leaves the preprocessor as `::f()`

Comment: I call the function the following way: AT24C256::f()